# Throw a coin $10$ times without knowing the mass distribution and get $10$ heads and $0$ tail, what is the probability of head in the $11$th time?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Throw **coin A** $10$ times without knowing the mass distribution and get $10$ heads and $0$ tails, what is the probability of facing up for the $11$th time?

Throw **coin B** $100$ times without knowing the mass distribution and get $99$ heads and $1$ tails, what is the probability of facing up for the $101$th time?

Which coin is more likely to face up in the next toss?

---

I already know that parameter estimation methods such as maximum likelihood estimation can be used to estimate the most likely mass distribution of this coin;

I already know that Laplace smoothing can help me better compare the difference between Coin A and Coin B;

But how should we calculate their probability of heading up in the next toss?

I just want a percentage.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If we can throw the coin ten times "without knowing the mass distribution," shouldn't we be able to throw it an eleventh time, again without knowing the mass disttibution?  You might be interested in the subject (and philosophy) of statistical inference.

Comment: You need a prior probability distribution for the parameter $p$ which is the probability of the coin landing heads up. For example, you might assume that $p$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$. Then you can use Bayes's theorem to update your beliefs about the value of $p$ based on the evidence.

Comment: I agree with @littleO . What you need is the concept of "Bayesian updating": https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading11.pdf

Comment: More concretely: The [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) for [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) or [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) [likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) is the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).  If you are OK with a uniform prior before the sequence of tosses, you can use $\text{Beta}(0, 0)$.

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches to this problem depending
on assumptions and statistical philosophy. One possibility is to take a Bayesian approach (as suggested in comments by @little), @Quillo, and @BrianTung.)

Let's say you have a chance to look at the coin before
you start tossing. If it 'looks like a fair coin' to
you, then you might start with a prior distribution on the true Heads probability
$\theta \sim \mathsf{Beta}(2,2)$ with density proportional to $$f(\theta) \propto \theta(1-\theta) = \theta^{2-1}(1-\theta)^{2-1},$$
for $0 < \theta < 1.$ [The symbol $\propto$ is read as "proportional to".]

There are various ways to characterize what you might
have in mind, making this particular choice of a prior distribution. One of them is that
you think there's a 95% chance that the true Heads
probability $\theta$ is in the interval $(0.0843, 0.9057)$ and that $E(\theta) = 0.5.$

```
q = qbeta(c(.025,.975) ,2 ,2);  q
[1] 0.09429932 0.90570068
```

After getting 10 Heads and 0 Tails in ten tosses, your
binomial likelihood function would be proportional to
$$g(x|\theta) \propto \theta^{10}(1-\theta)^0.$$

Using Bayes' Theorem to obtain the posterior distribution on $\theta$ you would have the posterior density function
proportional to
$$h(\theta|x) = f(\theta)\times g(x|\theta)\\  \propto \theta^{2-1}(1-\theta)^{2-1} \times 
\theta^{10}(1-\theta)^0 \\ = \theta^{12-1}(1-\theta)^{2-1},$$
which we recognize at the kernel (density function without norming factor) of $\mathsf{Beta}(12,2),$ which has
$E(\theta) = 12/14 = 6/7 = 0.8571$ and
$P(0.6397 <\theta< 0.9808) = 0.95.$ Also, taking the
mean as your guide, you might say a likely value
of $P(X_{11} = 1) - P(\mathrm{H\;on\;11th}) = 6/7.$
Or if you wanted to give an interval estimate,
you could say that probability is in the interval
$(0.6387,0.9808).$

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 12, 2)
[1] 0.6397026 0.9807933
```

The answer does depend in a small way on your choice
of the prior beta distribution, but it would not
have been much different if you had chosen $\mathsf{Beta}(1,1),$ or $\mathsf{Beta}(.5,.5)$ or some other beta
distribution with small and equal shape parameters.

Similar arguments could be used for Coin B with 99 Heads and 1 Tails in 100 tosses.

*Notes:* If you were to take a frequentist probability approach
and consider it a Law of the Universe that this
particular coin is fair, then you would not be much impressed
by the evidence of ten Heads in a row and you would
say that the coin has had an 'anomalous lucky streak,'
and that its probability of Heads on the 11th toss
is still $1/2.$ This is not much different from
a Bayesian starting with a prior distribution something
like $\mathsf{Beta}(10^6, 10^6),$ which would
overwhelm any results from only ten tosses and give
essentially a probability $1/2$ on the 11th toss.

A traditional frequentist statistician might wonder if we should update our estimate of the probability of Heads after 10 Heads in a row, but
it is not clear what procedure should be used for that. It may be too much to say the coin must
be two Headed.